# 404 response when deploy vuejs using "npm run build"

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vuejs3

I'm deploying vue3 application on window server (IIS). When i start website at url look like: app.mvb1900.com and using menu to switch to /map (app.mvb1900.com/map) => it still work
But when im reload or start website at app.mvb1900.com/map => it response 404

Please help me.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect all routes in IIS to `/`.  This is the nature of SPAs, that only a single html file `index.html` is ever served no matter the URL path.

You can add something like the below rewrite rule to a [web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-7.0) file in your project's root directory.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Vue SPA" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```